# Horror story writer moves with his family into a house where the previous family was murderered

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I watched a movie a few months back. The movie starts with four people *hanging by their necks* on a tree. The hero is a writer of horror stories. He comes to a house along with his family. He finds a projector with several film rolls on the attic. He watches those films everyday. All films were based on a murder case. The movie's investigation goes like this:

> A child in the house gets haunted. He kills the family members. Well, they say something that the children do that as a devotion to some god. The interesting link between every murders is that the *murdered* family had stayed for a while in a house where people were previously murdered. The story goes on like the next family stay in this house and go to another house where they get murdered by their children.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [*Sinister*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinister_%28film%29). I am 100% certain this is what you're looking for!!

*Sinister* is the story of Ellison Oswalt *(Ethan Hawke)*, a true crime writer. The events unfold when he moves into a house where grizzly murders had taken place. He finds a box of home movies which, unknown to him, puts his family in grave danger.

Comment: If you quoted this short synopsis (as the block quote suggests) where did the quote come from (it’s not from Wikipedia article, as far as I can see)? If, to the contrary, you paraphrased it (bad grammar and all), why did you put it in the block quote?